# I need to make a programm that prints not only the result but also how that amount is calculated

Tags: python

I have to make a program that calculates the sum of consecutive numbers 1 + 2 + 3 + ... until its value is at least the number entered by the user and also prints not only the result but also how that amount is calculated.

Here is my code

```
    where_to=int(input("Number: "))
    number=1
    sum=1
    while sum < where_to:
     number += 1
     sum += number"
```

Comment: You don't print anything currently.

Comment: ```print(f"{' + '.join(str(i) for i in range(1,num+1))} = {sum(range(1,num+1))}")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this quite simple:

```py
where_to=int(input("Number: "))
number=1
sum=1
out = "1"
while sum < where_to:
    out = out + " + " + str(number)
    number += 1
    sum += number
print(out)
```

Comment: There is an extra ```"```

Answer (score 0):

The following would print the sum for every step of the calculation:

```
where_to = int(input("Number: "))
total = number = 0  # don't call variable "sum" (shadows built-in)
while total < where_to:
     number += 1
     total += number
     print(total)
```